Pandas - New column calculation is repeating the results for all the rows
I'm kind of desperate here trying to figure out a solution to my problem and hope anyone out there has an idea.
I have 2 DF:

Security Role Definition(roleDefDF) that contains access rules to information based on departments assign to each role (~3000 different roles)




ROLE_NAME
DEPARTMENT_CODES




Role 1
DPT_60001716,DPT_60009998


Role 2
DPT_62068951




Employee Details (factTabDF) that contains organizational data for all the company employees (~200,000 employees)




INDEX
EMPLOYEE_ID
DEPARTMENT_CODE




0
EMP_001
DPT_60001716


1
EMP_002
DPT_62068951


2
EMP_003
DPT_62068951


3
EMP_004
DPT_60001716


4
EMP_005
DPT_60009998


5
EMP_006
DPT_60009999



And the expected result would be a DF like the one below, that contains the employees and the role that has visibility of each one:



INDEX
EMPLOYEE_ID
ROLE_NAME




0
EMP_001
Role 1


1
EMP_002
Role 2


2
EMP_003
Role 2


3
EMP_004
Role 1


4
EMP_005
Role 1


5
EMP_006




I have been able to achieve the expected result but iterating through roleDefDF which resulted an extremely expensive solution with terrible performance.
So I have changed the approach, basically now I'm trying to get the list of indexes from the employee table that would be visible for every role and then store that list (as text) in a new column:
roleDefDF['INDEX_OF_VISIBLE_EMPLOYEES'] = ','.join(str(x) for x in factTabDF.loc[factTabDF['DEPARTMENT_CODE'].apply(lambda x: any([x in roleDefDF['DEPARTMENT_CODES'].str.split(",",expand=False).values[0]]))].index.tolist())

This was the expectation:



ROLE_NAME
DEPARTMENT_CODES
INDEX_OF_VISIBLE_EMPLOYEES




Role 1
DPT_60001716,DPT_60009998
0,3,4


Role 2
DPT_62068951
1,2



If I test the above code using just the first row from roleDefDF, this works as expected:



ROLE_NAME
DEPARTMENT_CODES
INDEX_OF_VISIBLE_EMPLOYEES




Role 1
DPT_60001716,DPT_60009998
0,3,4



The same happens if I do it only for the second row:



ROLE_NAME
DEPARTMENT_CODES
INDEX_OF_VISIBLE_EMPLOYEES




Role 2
DPT_62068951
1,2




After all the context, finally my problem: New column calculation is repeating the results for all the rows

But as soon as I remove the one row filter from roleDefDF I see a different result:



ROLE_NAME
DEPARTMENT_CODES
INDEX_OF_VISIBLE_EMPLOYEES




Role 1
DPT_60001716,DPT_60009998
0,3,4


Role 2
DPT_62068951
0,3,4



Whatever was the result of the first Role, it is repeated in the rest.
Does anybody has an idea, what is happening here?

Here is one way of doing this. first Explode the DEPARTMENT_CODES in roleDefDF so that each department code is in its own row, then
merge this exploded dataframe with the factTabDF on DEPARTMENT_CODE. Finally, group by ROLE_NAME to aggregate the employee IDs.
import pandas as pd

roleDefDF = pd.DataFrame({
    'ROLE_NAME': ['Role 1', 'Role 2'],
    'DEPARTMENT_CODES': ['DPT_60001716,DPT_60009998', 'DPT_62068951']
})

factTabDF = pd.DataFrame({
    'INDEX': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'EMPLOYEE_ID': ['EMP_001', 'EMP_002', 'EMP_003', 'EMP_004', 'EMP_005', 'EMP_006'],
    'DEPARTMENT_CODE': ['DPT_60001716', 'DPT_62068951', 'DPT_62068951', 'DPT_60001716', 'DPT_60009998', 'DPT_60009999']
})

roleDefDF['DEPARTMENT_CODE'] = roleDefDF['DEPARTMENT_CODES'].str.split(',')
roleDefDF_exploded = roleDefDF.explode('DEPARTMENT_CODE')

merged_df = pd.merge(factTabDF, roleDefDF_exploded, how='left', left_on='DEPARTMENT_CODE', right_on='DEPARTMENT_CODE')

result_df = merged_df.groupby(['INDEX', 'EMPLOYEE_ID'])['ROLE_NAME'].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x.dropna())).reset_index()

print(result_df)

which gives
   INDEX EMPLOYEE_ID ROLE_NAME
0      0     EMP_001    Role 1
1      1     EMP_002    Role 2
2      2     EMP_003    Role 2
3      3     EMP_004    Role 1
4      4     EMP_005    Role 1
5      5     EMP_006          


As @Serge said, you can perform an explode→merge→groupby pattern for this problem.
Since you updated your problem with a new facet, I wanted to show how to accomplish
that portion.
import pandas as pd

roleDefDF = pd.DataFrame({
    'ROLE_NAME': ['Role 1', 'Role 2'],
    'DEPARTMENT_CODES': ['DPT_60001716,DPT_60009998', 'DPT_62068951']
})

factTabDF = pd.DataFrame({
    'INDEX': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'EMPLOYEE_ID': ['EMP_001', 'EMP_002', 'EMP_003', 'EMP_004', 'EMP_005', 'EMP_006'],
    'DEPARTMENT_CODE': ['DPT_60001716', 'DPT_62068951', 'DPT_62068951', 'DPT_60001716', 'DPT_60009998', 'DPT_60009999']
})

expanded = (
    roleDefDF
    .assign(DEPARTMENT_CODES=lambda d: d['DEPARTMENT_CODES'].str.split(','))
    .explode('DEPARTMENT_CODES')
    .rename(columns={'DEPARTMENT_CODES': 'DEPARTMENT_CODE'})
    .merge(factTabDF, on='DEPARTMENT_CODE', how='right')
)
print(expanded)
#   ROLE_NAME DEPARTMENT_CODE  INDEX EMPLOYEE_ID
# 0    Role 1    DPT_60001716      0     EMP_001
# 1    Role 2    DPT_62068951      1     EMP_002
# 2    Role 2    DPT_62068951      2     EMP_003
# 3    Role 1    DPT_60001716      3     EMP_004
# 4    Role 1    DPT_60009998      4     EMP_005
# 5       NaN    DPT_60009999      5     EMP_006

compressed = (
    expanded
    .astype({'INDEX': 'string'})
    .groupby('ROLE_NAME', as_index=False).agg(
        DEPARTMENT_CODES=('DEPARTMENT_CODE', ','.join),
        INDEX_OF_VISIBLE_EMPLOYEES=('INDEX', ','.join),
    )
)
print(compressed)
#   ROLE_NAME                        DEPARTMENT_CODES INDEX_OF_VISIBLE_EMPLOYEES
# 0    Role 1  DPT_60001716,DPT_60001716,DPT_60009998                      0,3,4
# 1    Role 2               DPT_62068951,DPT_62068951                        1,2

